# Perl testing (Automation) to check Cookies Attributes and display pass or fail

Tags: perl, automation

How to write Perl Module program to check the cookies attributes for secure cookie or Httponly flag and display the result whether it contains secure and Httponly flag using test modules.Below is the code for Cookie.please can some one give the code.

```
use strict; 
use LWP::simple;
use LWP::UserAgent; 
use HTTP::Request;  

my $URL = 'https://www.gmail.com/'; 

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();  
my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $URL);  
my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $URL, $header);  
my $response =  $ua->request($request); 


print $_ foreach @ {$response->headers()->{'set-cookie'}};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ok or not ok"? how would we tell whether a cookie is OK?

Comment: To Check whether it is Secure or not and it is Httponly or not,,

Answer (score 0):

Here is some reading: http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch11_01.htm

It is going to save the cookies to a file then you could check that file:

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
   file     => "/some/where/cookies.lwp",
   autosave => 1,
);
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$browser->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar );
```